# Access DIV element from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

here is the following DIV structure:

```
<div class="demo">
    <div id="tabs">
        <div id="tabs-1"></div>
        <div id="tabs-2"></div>
</div></div>
```

How do I access 'tabs-2' from JavaScript?

```
var plot2 = $.jqplot ('tabs-2', [points], {...
```

This JavaScript code works fine only for the 1st-level DIV containers, e.g. 'demo'.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
document.getElementById('tabs-2')
```

?

Comment: Do you mean this? var plot2 = $.jqplot (document.getElementById('tabs-2'), [points], {... This does not work for me.

Comment: @YouKuper I don't know what is `jqplot` (I guess it's a library). But if you want a reference to the element, yes, use that.

Comment: @YouKuper It seems you don't need a reference to the element, you can pass only the id. Then, `$.jqplot ('tabs-2', [points], {...` should work. Can you give us a jsfiddle with the complete code?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('tabs-2')
```

Try this..