# how to access element in div using javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access DIV element from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248617/access-div-element-from-javascript)

I have a HTML code like :

```
<div id="headerlist" >
<h3> Enrollment Efficiency</h3>
</div>
```

I have to access element Enrollment Efficiency

I am trying with :

```
var headerlist = document.getElementsById('headerlist');
alert("the value of headerlist is "+ headerlist.firstChild);
```

But its not working.

Comment: These kind  of questions can be easily resolved using Google...

Comment: The difference is, we're trying to create an archive of useful Q&A's, this won't help anyone in the future. Besides, it has been asked a hundred times over. IMO this is pollution.

Comment: Check my answer below once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a typo. It is `getElementById()` (no plural `s` there).

```
var headerlist = document.getElementById('headerlist');
```

An `id` should be unique throughout the document, hence only one element should be returned by this functions. If there *could* be more than one element matched, like with `getElementsByName()`, there is a plural `s`.

**EDIT**

As mentioned by @Cerbrus: The `firstChild` attribute, just points to first child element, and not to its contents.

To remarks here:

1. The `firstChild` in your example is just a whitespace text node. if you want the next non-whitespace node use [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.firstElementChild) ([supported in most modern browswers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t81)).
2. To display the contents, use something like [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) or [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Node.textContent).

Comment: You might want to mention that `firstChild` isn't going to get the desired result, like I did.

Comment: I think it's also a good idea to mention that `firstElementChild` is not widely supported yet. Sorry for nagging :P You still have my +1

Comment: @Cerbrus Added a link for browser compatibility. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Function `getElementByid` is singular, not plural.

Comment: ...contrary to `getElementsByClassName` which is plural

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, remove the `s` from `getElementsById` --> `getElementById`.

Also, `firstChild` will return the textNode seperating the `div` and `h3`. Try this:

```
function getFirstChild(element) {
    do { 
        element = element.firstChild;
    } while (element && element.firstChild!== 1);
    return element;
}
// Usage: getFirstChild(headerlist);
```

Resulting in:

```
var headerlist = document.getElementById('headerlist');
console.log("the value of headerlist is ", getFirstChild(headerlist).innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to access the data of inner HTML elements. So here is your code how you can achieve it

**[CHECK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/kbAvM/)**

you can access all child of parent element in following manner.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="amu">
<div id="a"> aa </div>
<h1>aaaa </h1>
<h3> bbbb </h3>
</div>

<div onclick="check()"> click Me </div>
</body>
<script>
function check() {
var childNodeArray = document.getElementById('amu').getElementsByTagName('*');
alert(childNodeArray.length);
for (i=0; i < childNodeArray.length; i++)
alert(childNodeArray[i].innerHTML);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code in jQuery (library in javascript)

```
alert($("#headerlist").eq(0).text());
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GDNJM/)

Comment: Why downvote? jQuery is a library on jquery and to select the element is more efficient

Comment: Don't bring a gun to a swordfight, don't answer native JS questions with jQuery, and HECK NO. jQuery is nowhere near as efficient as native JS.

Comment: Nothing mentioned about jQuery in the question, they might not know anything about it. Absolutely useless...

Comment: Sure but jQuery is more easy to implement and to use  I only give another solution with a ajavascript library. @Cerbrus

Comment: Easy `=/=` good. At least, not always. Let people get the basics of JS first, before tossing them a library. Especially if they don't ask for jQuery.